# Proving parallel planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given two planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (or perhaps higher dimensions) in parametric form, what ways are there to prove that they are parallel (or not parallel)? A friend suggested equating the spans and trying to solve for the 4 parameters, but I don't think this works (I'm fairly certain it only finds a vector whose span lies on the spans of the planes). Currently I'm trying to show that the direction vectors of the second plane lie in the span of the direction vectors of the first plane. Is there any other way to do these types of questions?

One example would be showing that the following planes are not parallel. $$\mathbb{x}=(1,-4,2,3)^T+\lambda_1(2,1,-2,7)^T+\lambda_2(-3,1,5,2)^T\;\text{for}\;\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{R} \\\mathbb{x}=(2,-4,1,3)^T+\mu_1(3,-1,2,4)^T+\mu_2(-1,4,2,6)^T\;\text{for}\;\mu_1,\mu_2\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: By "plane" you perhaps mean a two-dimensional affine subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$?  It would help if you shared how these are currently represented, so that suggestions can be based on that.

Comment: Also, what does "parallel" mean?  Nonintersecting?  Or coincident normal spaces?

Comment: Sorry I'm only just starting linear algebra, I think parallel means that the span of the direction vectors is equivalent. We've classified nonintersecting planes into 'parallel' and 'skew' planes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data that determines the parametric equations of a plane in $\Bbb{R}^n$ for $n \geq 3$ is given by a triple $(p,\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2)$ where $p$ is point, $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2$ are two linearly independent vectors, and the corresponding parametric equations are given by the system of linear equations
$$
x = p + t\mathbf{v}_1 + s\mathbf{v}_2
$$
where $s,t \in \Bbb{R}$ are the parameters and $x = (x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$ is the vector of coordinates.

Now observe that two planes $(p,\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2), (q,\mathbf{w}_1,\mathbf{w}_2)$ are parallel if and only if their translations to the origin coincide, i.e. if and only if $\{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{w}_1,\mathbf{w}_2\}$ contains exactly two linearly independent vectors.

An easy way to check this is to check if the matrix with columns $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{w}_1,\mathbf{w}_2$ has rank $2$.